# SVN Patch - with multiple files

Tags: svn, command-line, diff, patch

I am trying to make a patch with multiple files in different directories. I don't want to include all my uncommitted files as I have a lot not applicable to the patch.

I know of this command to create a patch with a specific file, only issue is this is one file:

```
svn diff -up original.php > filename.patch
```

Is there any way to do this with multiple files in different directories ?

Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try used: `svn diff -r BEGIN_REVISION:END_REVISION > patch_file.patch`
This will make the patch on all modified files.

If you want create patch for concrete files, you can enumerate them before `>`.

`svn diff dir_name_1/first.php dir_name_2/second.php > patch_file.patch`

For one directory:
`svn diff -uRp dir_name > patch_file.patch`

I'll hope it helps you.

Comment: Great that helps, enumerating the files with directory structure before the > is exactly what i was looking for ^^

Comment: According to http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-diff.html This shows only the differences with a few lines of context. It is harder to read than a visual file compare, but will show all the changes together